# How to detect unused variables in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, lint, unused-variables

Is there a way to detect unused variables in Typescript (something like ESLint in Javascript)?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

As of version 2.0, Typescript has built-in support for detecting unused local variables and parameters. The compiler flags are as follows:

```
--noUnusedLocals                    Report Errors on Unused Locals.
--noUnusedParameters                Report Errors on Unused Parameters.
```

Comment: What if you just want these as warnings?

Comment: In that case you could use ESLint and configure it to emit a warning instead of an error for this rule: https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-unused-vars

Comment: I didn't get How should I use the above comments. I am sorry I am new to this Angular stuff. can you help me to say how to use this comments ?

Answer (score 20):

You can also detect unused variables in Typescript by updating the project’s `tsconfig.json` file to include `noUnusedLocals` and `noUnusedParameters`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 13):

You can use TSLint instead.

https://palantir.github.io/tslint/

There's a rule for that: https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/no-unused-variable/

**Edit:**

Although this works, if you are using TypeScript 2 +, the compiler flags/options mentioned in the other answers.

Comment: This is the way forward!

Comment: It is, as I said after editing the response, you should use the solution proposed by @Taytay

Comment: In light of the community's desire to keep this rule, it has been *UNDEPRECATED*! woop woop! https://github.com/palantir/tslint/pull/2256

Comment: It has been deprecated again unfortunately